# Android facebook profle get name

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-fragments, authentication

I'm trying to retrive the profile name from a facebook user that has logged in/ is logged in. It only lets me retrive the name if I'm already logged in on facebook before I run my applikation otherwise it will be null. I'm trying to retrive the name and display it in a textview object.

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView mTextDetails;
    private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
    private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) { // The thing you want to do when you got permission
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            if(profile != null){
                mTextDetails.setText("Welcome " + profile.getName());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

        }
    };

    public MainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        mTextDetails = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_details);
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton)view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");//Only ask if you must
        loginButton.setFragment(this);
        loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, mCallback);


        return view;
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode, data);

    }

}
```

Comment: Try changes your read permission with `loginButton.setReadPermissions(Collections.singletonList("public_profile, email","user_friends"));`

Comment: Then I'm getting the error when trying to login: Invalid Scope: public_profile. Before changing to your suggestion I was able to login but not fetch the profilename, only when prelogged in on the facebook app before launching my app

Comment: Ah, maybe you can try my answer after you changes your read permission

Comment: are you sure that
´loginButton.setReadPermissions(Collections.singletonList("pu‌​blic_profile, email","user_friends"));´  it says its an error there.

Comment: ah wait, `loginButton.setReadPermissions(Collections.singletonList("pu‌​blic_profile, email,user_friends"));` i changes the " position

Comment: hm I still get error: Invalid Scope:public_profile. I could just do like this: first time I log in I fetch the name and save it in sharedpreferences for later use.      then just fetch the name from sharedpreferences when I start the app next time to get the user name? I can't find other way to do this

Comment: maybe you can share the error log?

Comment: There is no error log, just in the app when I try to log in it says Invalid scope: public_profile

Comment: Btw what Facebook SDK version u use?

Comment: the latest, started with this 2 days ago

Comment: Hemm, i think you can follow your way to save name when first time login to SharedPreference for later use, sorry if make you confuse with my suggestion but did you try to fetch the profile using the GraphRequest?

Comment: No, I am thankfull for your help, very appreciated. I might have formulated my question in a nonunderstanding way

Comment: Did you try using GraphRequest? I using that & working for me?

Comment: graphrequest and the code you provided above, ´loginButton.setReadPermissions(Collections.singletonList("pu‌​‌​blic_profile, email,user_friends"));´ ?

Comment: Yes, with the code loginButton.setReadPermissions(Collections.singletonList("pu‌​blic_profile, email"));

Comment: hm ye this works but how do I fetch the name once I'm already logged in? When I close my app, I don't have to login again hence the textview wont do the mTextDetails.setText(name); since I've put it in the onCompleted method. This means when I'm already logged in I can't get the profile name since the  JSONObject is a local variable in the public void onCompleted method wich will only run once trying to logIn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use GraphRequest to get the profilename after you changes your read permission to `loginButton.setReadPermissions(Collections.singletonList("pu‌​blic_profile, email"));` the graphrequest is

```
@Override
        public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(
                                JSONObject object,
                                GraphResponse response) {

                            try {
                                if (object != null) {
                                    String name  = object.getString("first_name") + " "+object.getString("last_name");
                                   }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {

                            }
                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email, first_name, last_name, gender");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you got a Facebook Application Key? 
You need one of those to access the Facebook API from your application which might explain why you are not getting results unless you are logged in, The application needs to authenticate to the Facebook API using the application key first.

[Link to Tutorial on how to get your key](http://www.shoutmeloud.com/how-to-acquire-your-facebook-api-key.html)

Comment: I've got an Applikations-ID and Key Hashes if that's what you refere to? I've followed the developer.facebook tutorial very thoroughly.